# ORDER BY SQL on many tables

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have this table

```
Table1
 id  |  name  |
  1  |   a    |
  2  |   c    |
```

and other table like this

```
Table2
 id  |  name  |
  1  |   b    |
  2  |   d    |
```

How can I sort this two table to result

> a b c d

[DONE READING THIS](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) but it will only gives me this result

> a c b d

when I try this

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 AS t1 JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id
ORDER BY t1.name ASC, t2.name ASC;
```

Comment: what is correct  logic of order .you can order by id also and it give same result.also Order by int column is always good.

Comment: @KumarHarsh i want to `order by` all from table1 and table2 column name

Comment: @KumarHarsh why is their no good logic to Order By name?

Comment: I deleted my comments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try taking a `UNION` of the two tables instead:

```
SELECT id, name
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name
FROM Table2
ORDER BY name
```

If you want to retain information about the original source of each record, you can add a column for that:

```
SELECT id, name, 't1' AS source
FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT id, name, 't2'
FROM Table2
ORDER BY name
```

**Update:**

If Codeigniter does not support `UNION` out of the box, you can always put the above query into a string and execute it natively:

```
$sql = "SELECT id, name FROM Table1 UNION ALL SELECT id, name FROM Table2 ORDER BY name";
$this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: so i should make it UNION instead of JOIN?

Comment: UNION seems to make the most sense to me.  Maybe have a look at the join option by @jelliaes as well.

Comment: but i dont get it where the `#TEMP_TBL` came from in his answer

Comment: Yeah use the union. It'll make your life much easier.

Comment: tnx @TimBiegeleisen for the answer

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
INTO #TEMP_TBL
FROM Table1 AS t1 
JOIN Table2 AS t2 
ON t2.id = t1.id

SELECT *
FROM #TEMP_TBL
ORDER BY ID, NAME

DROP TABLE #TEMP_TBL
```

Comment: can you explain me where that #TEMP_TBL came from?

Comment: @PureRhymerOrganization #TEMP_TBL is a temporary table where I inserted the combined values from table1 and table2. The query is compatible with SQL SERVER. Btw, if the two tables have the same value, why not just use a single table for them?

Comment: actually it has other data thats why I didnt join them too. So if its not SQL SERVER it is compatible too?

Comment: for example MySql

Comment: It will definitely work with sql server. I'm not sure with mysql. I think they have different syntax for creating temporary tables.

Comment: Are you using mysql? If yes, i think you have to remove the tag sql-server so you could get the right answer for your question.

Comment: im doing both sql-server and mysql

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use join then try below query

```
select * from (select x.* from table1 as x  left join table2 as y on x.id = y.id) as z order by z.name;
```

Comment: yes, so it will compare data by id, merge record and return result set

Comment: oh i see but it was so hard to convert it in codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

We can use this also:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT id, NAME FROM Table1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, NAME FROM Table2) t ORDER BY name
```

Comment: You don't need to use a subquery to order here, and in fact the subquery could massively slow things down.

Comment: Yes, in case of huge data but this also should be known so I have posted it just as an alternative.